# How to check if customer is already subscribed to newsletter

Tags: customer, magento-1.6, newsletter, ce-1.6.2.0

I need to check if the customer is subscribed to news letter or not. Currently I am using this code and it is returning nothing:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $status = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getIsSubscribed();
    echo $status;
    die();
}
```

This is not giving anything. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alternatively you can try this,
if you have the customer's email address:

```
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
if ($subscriber->getId()) {
     // put your logic here...
}
```

Or if you have customer ID then you can directly check in **`newsletter_subscriber`** table to check if customer ID exists or not.

Comment: i used this code.$email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
    $status = $subscriber->isSubscribed();

Comment: how could I check whether a guest customer (NOT LOGGED IN customer) has subscribed for nesletter, in the same customer session.

Comment: @ravisoni great answer!!! :)

Comment: can you tell me `is_subscribed` is in which table save or is it save in session

Comment: @ND17 the status of a newsletter subscriber is stored in `\`newsletter_subscriber\`.\`subscriber_status\``. Note that the table name may have a prefix depending on your configuration.

Comment: i did the same in this event "sales_order_place_after" but not get subscriber id in observer.

Comment: this is not working for me. is there any other idea how to get checkbox value to check customer subscribe or not with newsletter subscription using observer.

Answer (score 7):

You have to check also the subscription status:

```
  if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        $email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getData('email');
        $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
        if($subscriber->getId())
        {
            $isSubscribed = $subscriber->getData('subscriber_status') == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer should be the accepted one, the other ones do not care if customer is unsubscribed or pending

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion none of the above answers are very convenient in that they either don't check if the customer is actually subscribed or don't handle the case where a subscription has not been found, so here goes:

```
$customerIsSubscribed = false;
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if ($customer) {
    $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
    $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
    if ($subscriber) {
        $customerIsSubscribed = $subscriber->isSubscribed();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added this code in observer.php file but not get anything about subscribe or not.

Answer (score 2):

To extend @Mufaddal's answer:

```
$subscriberModel = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
$subbed = ($subscriberModel->isSubscribed() ? true : false);
```

This way you check if the subscription record is present AND if the subscription status is true.

Comment: if you use isSubscribed() then it  not require to  use `$subscriberModel->getId()`