# Check if email already subscribed (on newsletter)

Tags: email, newsletter, magento2.2.3

I have a custom popup for email signup to the newsletter, and add the email via a custom module, which works fine.. but, It seems to allow duplicate emails, which I don't want.

How can I check if an email is already subscribed?

One additional question if anyone knows; When guests subscribe with their email, can I also add their names somehow, or would I need to add a custom field to db first?

Comment: which Magento version ?

Comment: oh yea, magento 2.2.3

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/how-to-check-if-customer-is-already-subscribed-to-newsletter

Comment: modifiy it in magneto2

Comment: can you check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134201/magento-2-check-if-customer-is-subscribed-to-newsletter